# random is not defined in python

Tags: python

I'm trying to produce a random integer `n`, and create a list of n random integers with values between 0 and 9.

Here is my code:

```
def randomNumbers(n):
    myList = []
    needMoreNumbers = True
    while (needMoreNumbers):
        randomNumber = int(random.random() * 10)
        myList.append(randomNumber)
        n = n -1
        if (n < 1):
            needMoreNumbers = False
    return myList
```

When I run it, it says:

```
NameError: global name 'random' is not defined
```

Comment: Did you remember to `import random` ?

Comment: Why don't you accept the answer?

Answer (score 59):

You haven't imported `random` module. Add this to the top of your script:

```
import random
```

Comment: what does the import function do? thank you for your help by the way.  I got it to work.

Comment: Take a look at python docs on [modules](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html) and [import](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#import).

Answer (score 5):

The script file name can't be "random.py", doing this will trigger a circular import making your program fail.