# Creating loops, being able to quit?

Tags: python

> I am making a basic game 2 players 1-3 dice to be selectable than whoever rolls the highest number wins. How do i make this work using python
>
> i am unsure how to loop the rolls and then be able to select quit, continue and to be able to select another number of dice to be rolled and goto the start screen. also what can be used to keep a score of this. This is the code i have.
>
> i am also having trouble with the if commands how do i make the dice selectable from 1 to 3 without displaying all of the options

```
Dice = input("Please select number of dice you would like to use (1-3)")
if Dice == "1":
    print("You have selected 1 dice")
 import random
 Roll1 = random.randrange(1,6)
print ("Player 1's Roll")
print(Roll1)
print ("Player 2's Roll")
print (Roll1)
#2 Dice Counter
  if Dice == "2":
    print("You have selected 2 dice")
import random
Roll2 = (random.randrange(2,12))
print ("Player 1's Roll")
print(Roll2)
print ("Player 2's Roll")
print (Roll22)

#3 Dice Counter
if Dice == "3":
    print("You have selected 3 dice")
import random
Roll3 = random.randrange(3,18)
print ("Player 1's Roll")
print(Roll3)
print ("Player 2's Roll")
print (Roll3)
while invalid_input :
            Dice()
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your logic inside a function for example `getDiceInput()`, this will return if the user inputs a valid option, if the user inputs a valid input which is between `(1-3)` the result will be printed, otherwise an invalid input message will be printed, now keep calling the `getDiceInput()` inside the loop until user inputs `-1` this will cause the loop `while (inputValue != -1)` to exit and goodbye message will be printed to exit, and use `randint` for generating random numbers, check following snippet :

```
   from random import randint


    def getDiceInput():
      Roll1 = 0
      Roll2 = 0
      validInput = 1
      Dice = input("Please select number of dice you would like to use (1-3) -1 to exit")
      if Dice == "1":
        print("You have selected 1 dice")
        Roll1 = int(randint(1,6))
        Roll2 = int(randint(1,6))

      #2 Dice Counter
      elif Dice == "2":
        print("You have selected 2 dice")
        Roll1 = int(randint(2,12))
        Roll2 = int(randint(2,12))

      #3 Dice Counter
      elif Dice == "3":
        print("You have selected 3 dice")
        Roll1 = randint(3,18)
        Roll2 = randint(3,18)

      elif Dice == "-1":
        validInput = -1

      else :
        print("invalid input reenter")
        validInput = 0


      if validInput == 1 :
        print ("Player 1's Roll")
        print(Roll1)
        print ("Player 2's Roll")
        print (Roll2)

      return validInput

    #Code execution will start here
    inputValue = getDiceInput()
    while (inputValue != -1):
      inputValue = getDiceInput()

    print("Goodbye")
```

Comment: Thankyou for this, could you please furthermore explain this? and what the functions are used for/doing

Answer (score -1):

Use the `random` module and the `randint` function.

```
from random import randint
```

Then to use it:

```
randint(0,10)
```

The above would generate a random integer between 0 and 10.

**Looping**

Use a `while` loop to loop the rolls.

```
condition = "play"
while condition == "play":
    #Your code here

    if(input("Enter 'play' to play again or 'quit' to stop the program and reveal the scores: ") == "quit"):
        #Break out of the loop
        break
    else:
         condition = "play"
```

**For the if's**
I would use some maths to generate the range of numbers in the `randint` or `randrange`. For example:

```
#Get input of dice to roll as integer
toRoll = int(input("Dice to roll: "))
#'Roll' the dice that many times
Roll = random.randrange(1*toRoll,6*toRoll)
```

Then use the `Roll` variable.
This will yield the same as using all the if statements (except the `print`s of course).

Comment: First, OP is already doing that. Second, your code has a syntax error.

Comment: He is not using `randint` and where is the syntax error?

Comment: They're using the very similar `randrange`. This doesn't address any part of the actual question.

Comment: He has edited the question since I posted the answer. Initially it had asked why `randrange` was not working.

Comment: Unfortunately, OP never specified the way in which `randrange` didn't work. It's certainly possible that they simply hadn't imported the module and were getting a `NameError`. Of course, if that was the problem, the solution would be a duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18727556/random-is-not-defined-in-python). Also, it's not "the `randint` module"; `randint` is a function, and the name of the module is `random`.

Comment: What code do i place in the loop. whenever i try this it says the break is outside the loop

Comment: Put the code for rolling the dice inside the loop before it asks if you want to play again.