# I am facing error in Python for the random.randint(0,1000)/1000. It says random is not defined

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait


browser = webdriver.Chrome('E:\Coding\PBL\chromedriver')
browser.get("https://www.youtube.com")


def login_with_username_and_password(browser, username, password):

    email_input = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('input[type=email]')

    email = username 

    for letter in email:
        email_input.send_keys(letter)
        wait_time = random.randint(0,1000)/1000
        time.sleep(wait_time)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [random is not defined in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18727556/random-is-not-defined-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

`random` is a module just like `selenium`

add `import random` to the top of your code